# Message error when retrieving a SPOnline Site after creating it using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection

I'm implementing some *PowerShell* scripts for helping my team create new *SharePoint Online* sites. One of these scripts follows these requirements:

- be able to create a site,
- be able to remove the site if previously exists,
- be able to return the site created

Seems to be easy using the *SharePoint Online Management Shell* and that's it but I'm facing an issue that throws the following error:

`Get-SPOSite : Error in proc_GetSitesAllowDenyList, no rowset returned.`

I get it sometimes, not always, but don't know why and don't find any explanation about it googling. Let me share my code and try to explain it:

```
    # Obtains the site if exists
    $Instance = Get-SPOSite $Url

    # Removes the site in case that exists and user requires
    If($null -ne $Instance -and $true -eq $RemoveIfExists) {
        Write-Host "Removing site "$Url"..."

        Remove-SPOSite $Url -Confirm:$false
        Remove-SPODeletedSite $Url -Confirm:$false

        $Instance = $null
    }

    # Creates the site if not exists
    If($null -eq $Instance) {
        Write-Host "Creating site "$Url"..."
        $Instance = New-SPOSite -Owner $Owner -Url $Url -Title $Title -StorageQuota $Quota -Template $Template
    }

    # Returns the site
    Get-SPOSite $Url
```

As I said, seems that everything runs perfectly fine but when reaching the last line throws the error. Do you think that I need to add some delay to let *SharePoint/Office 365* completely do all the stuff need before retrieving the site?

Comment: yep, would suggest adding some delay. It looks like it is taking some time to clear the site collections.

Comment: yes, creating SC on SPO can takes from 1-60 minutes :) so you need to create delay